# Concatenate all items with matching FKey's

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has a `PKey`, a `FKey`, a `LineNum`, and a `TextLine`.

In my table, I have multiple results from the `FKey`. It's a 1 to many relationship.

What I want to do is have the `TextLine`s that match the `FKey` be concatenated into a single row. (The reason for this is that we're converting from an old COBOL database to T-SQL, and transferring the information to a new database with a different structure, where these "Comments" will all be handled by a single field)

My end query will look something like this:

```
SELECT Fkey, Line1 + Line2..., 
FROM Table1
```

The issue is that there is a non-consistent number of lines. In addition, I'm trying to avoid any dynamic queries, because I want un-trained/basic users to be able to modify and customize this query. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to get all the data in a single row:

```
select 
    t.FKey,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + textline
            from Table1 where FKey = t.FKey
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as ConcatTextLines
from 
    Table1 t
group by t.FKey
```

There will be some size limitations on the ConcatTextLines column so this may not be applicable if you have thousands of line for some foreign keys.

Comment: I think I don't ever have more than 5-6 rows, so it shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for the suggestion!